# Getting PHP to run apps on Linux Box

Tags: php, linux

At preset we have need to launch apps on a linux box remotely

To do this we have php script that is run at boot via the rc.local file.  This php script watches a command file.  This has commands written to it.

The php script has trouble running some apps.  For instance it can boot X11, but it can't run an app that is meant for X11.

But, if we run the php script from a terminal, them the system works just just fine

Here is the contents of the rc.local file (this fails).

`sudo -u jacob /usr/bin/php /home/listener/ListenerThread.php > /var/www/html/out.txt &`

The user jacob as sudo root access with no need for passwords

Please help

Comment: You need to give us the error. Is the issue purely that X11 apps don't work?

Comment: So are you running a X11 app or a PHP script?

Comment: You most likely have a permission issue (ie, php is being executed by a lower permission than user `jacob`.  Try running your 'tasks' under another privileged account, or verify access permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely if it's an X11 issue the children aren't having `DISPLAY` set in their environment, but without error messages we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I would suggest is to start X11 at boot and put the line that launches your script into your `.xinitrc`. This way your script will be able to run GUI programs correctly.

If you don't like that solution, then try running your gui apps from within the script like this: `env "DISPLAY=:0.0" your_gui_app`